# How to get the lat/lon of multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a code that allows the user to place multiple markers on the map just by click on the map. So each marker is placed on the map.
My question, how can I gather all the markers lat/lon in an array?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: e.latLng,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(e) {
    this.setMap(null);
  });
});
```

I have here demonstrate here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/1d0e6tut/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in the `click` listener, add marker to some global array:

```
var markers = [];
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: e.latLng,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker); // add marker to the global array

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(e) {
    this.setMap(null);
    delete markers[markers.indexOf(marker)]; // remove marker from array
  });
});
```